# Unable to run WSAD in client machine

Tags: websphere

Hi I am trying to run WSAD in Client login but its not starting up and giving the error as below

```
Application started: wclight
[02/09/09 15:11:27:656 CST] 41104110 WebContainer  E BRVE01E: Failed to Start Transport on host , port 80. The most likely cause is that the port is already in use. Please ensure that no other applications are using this port and restart the server. com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.TransportException: Failed to start transport http: java.net.BindException: Address in use: bind
```

I understand that it is a network port issue but seems there are none using this port when I scanned through netstat -n
Could there be any other reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the server list, double-click the target server on which the project runs.  The server details are shown in the top right window.  Click the Port tab at the bottom of that window. 
To avoid the port conflicts,  change the 9080 ports in both the Host alias list and the HTTP 
transport list.  Also, change the Location service daemon port (9000 by default) and ORB
bootstrap port (900 by default).
[IBM](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/dw/wes/pdf/SetupPortletDevEnv.pdf)